# Call function after $.each method

Tags: jquery, arrays, asynchronous, each

I'm using the $.each method on an array to save files to local folder.  How can I perform a function once the .each method has finished with last file in array?  .done method not working.

```
 function downloadStartData() {
        $.each(startUpimageFilesArray,
            function (index, entry) {
                saveTofolder(entry.addy, entry.nameOfFile)
            });       
 };
 function saveTofolder(url, fileName) {
        try {
             WinJS.xhr({
                url: url,
                responseType: "blob",
             }).done(
                function writeBlobToFile(result) {
                var blob=result.response;
                var lFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData; 
                var storeOption = Windows.Storage.CreateCollisionOption;
                lFolder.current.localFolder.createFileAsync(fileName, storeOption.replaceExisting
             ).then(function(file) {
               file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite
              ).then(function(output) {
                  var input = blob.msDetachStream();
                  Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStream.copyAsync(input, output
               ).then(function () output.flushAsync(
                ).then(function () {
                   input.close();
                       output.close();
                  )};
               )};
             )};
          )};
        )};
  }
catch (e) {
    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Exception while using XMLHttpRequest object 
    " + e, "sample", "error");
        }
};
```

Comment: Are you looking to run code when "all files are finished saving" or "last file started saving"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - When all files are finished saving.

Comment: return new promise for each file from saveToFolder method, mark that promise complete in last part of save method next to `close` and than wait till all promises are complete with something like [join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211774.aspx) or jQuery equivalent http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your most inner ***then*** function in the `saveToFolder`'s ***done*** can do it. You just need to confirm your function is called **after all saving are done**. So you can pass another function to indicate wheather currently completed saving is the last one, if yes, then perform your function.

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
// add a new parameter "fnCompleted" to your saveTofolder
function saveTofolder(url, fileName, fnCompleted){ 
    // some other operation omited
    // below is the most inner then
    .then(function () {
         input.close();
         output.close();
         fnCompleted();
    });
}

function downloadStartData() {
    var allFilesCount = startUpimageFilesArray.length, completed = 0;
    function checkIfCompleted(){
        completed++;

        // if this is the last one, do the work
        if(completed >= allFilesCount){
            // do something
        }
    }

    $.each(startUpimageFilesArray,
        function (index, entry) {
            saveTofolder(entry.addy, entry.nameOfFile, checkIfCompleted)
    });
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

`each` is synchronous.

You have asynchronous code in `saveToFolder`. You can pass callback to `saveToFolder` than will be called after current iteration finished.

```
function downloadStartData() {
    var len = startUpimageFilesArray.length;
    function callback() {
        len--;
        if(len==0) {
            // Write your "done" code here!
        }
    }
       $.each(startUpimageFilesArray,
           function (index, entry) {
               saveTofolder(entry.addy, entry.nameOfFile, callback)
           });       
};

// ... 
                ).then(function () {
                  input.close();
                      output.close();
                      callback(); 
                 )};
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The calling code must have some way to wait for `saveToFolder` to complete. You can make it return a promise:

```
function saveTofolder(url, fileName) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        try {
             WinJS.xhr({
                url: url,
                responseType: "blob",
             }).done(
                function writeBlobToFile(result) {
                var blob=result.response;
                var lFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData; 
                var storeOption = Windows.Storage.CreateCollisionOption;
                lFolder.current.localFolder.createFileAsync(fileName, storeOption.replaceExisting
             ).then(function(file) {
               file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite
              ).then(function(output) {
                  var input = blob.msDetachStream();
                  Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStream.copyAsync(input, output
               ).then(function () output.flushAsync(
                ).then(function () {
                   input.close();
                       output.close();
                   deferred.resolve();
                  )};
               )};
             )};
          )};
        )};
  }
catch (e) {
    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Exception while using XMLHttpRequest object 
    " + e, "sample", "error");
    deferred.fail();
        }
    return deferred.Promise();
};
```

Now, rather than `jquery.each`, you can use `jquery.map` to create an array of returned promises:

```
function downloadStartData() {
        var promises = $.map(startUpimageFilesArray,
            function (entry, index) {
                return saveTofolder(entry.addy, entry.nameOfFile)
            }); 
        return $.when(promises); // Returns a new promise that waits for all of them to complete   
 };
```